# Email server issues to outlook users

Tags: email, outlook, server, smtp, vps

I'm using my own email server to send and receive my emails. Therefor I've set up a VPS at Tilaa.com which also acts as my webserver.

On the webserver I have DirectAdmin setup which takes care of my administrative things.

The problem is that I can receive and send emails but Outlook, Live and Hotmail refuse the receive any emails coming from my email server. Gmail does work f.e. ( Not even in junk folders )

When the receiver at Outlook/live or hotmail adds my email address to the safe list, emails do get through.

My domain is virtualfarmingworld.com

What I have done? 
 - Setup SPF record
 - Setup DKIM record
 - Setup A record mail.virtualfarmingworld.com to server IP 84.22.113.42

[http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3avirtualfarmingworld.com&run=toolpage#](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3Avirtualfarmingworld.com&run=toolpage#)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Regards,
Ciryk Popeye

Answer (score 0):

Ciryk,

Hotmail can be a bit tricky, if it's being blocked completely. Then most likely your IP is on their internal blacklist. If it's showing up in their SPAM folder it can be a number of reason. The headers from the email in Hotmail will tell you why it's in the SPAM folder.

Look for `SRV:<value>` `PCL: <Value>` and `SCL: <Value>`

PCL stands for Phising Confidence Level and SCL stands for Spam Confidence Level.

You should run your email through this [Mail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/), it really does point out a lot of issues. It may or may not solve the hotmail issue, but they have this [inbox tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/services/inboxtester/) their that really awesome that will show you other places you're having issues mailing to. Keep in mind, the previous owner of the IP might of spammed from it and caused issues.

I also notice by helping a lot of people that after signing up to [Microsoft Junk Mail Reporting System](https://postmaster.live.com/snds/jmrp.aspx), wait a few days and then delivery results are better with hotmail. I did a scan on you IP and I think you did that already signed up?

You're also on this blacklist: http://www.dnsblchile.org/

Which is really easy to get off, normally takes a couple of hours after you filled out the form.

Comment: Hello Henry, thanks for the reply. I did the Mail Tester and returned only critical errors saying I should upgrade to their pro version so I'm guessing I'm good with that. I will now fill in the form for the postmaster.live.com and see. The only issue I'm having now is that I'm only allowed to send the authorization email too one of tilaa's ( my VPS ) email accounts. I already contacted them and I'll see what they say.

Comment: No problem - The pro version is less than the cost of a breakfast and can save you a weeks of frustration. If my answer helped you in anyway, would appreciate the upvote.